# Handling NULL data from DataGridView values to INSERT in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I'm using `C# Winforms` to `INSERT` some `NULL` or `Empty` values from the `DataGridView` to my `SQL Server`. But there is an error at this line.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Since it is expecting a value that is not NULL (Please do correct me if I'm wrong). This is the code for my `INSERT` query.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=" + ip + "," + port + "; Database=records; User ID=" + sqlid + "; Password=" + sqlpass + ""))
{
    conn.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridWork.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[workorder]
                                            ([Work Order]
                                            ,[Plate No.]
                                            ,[Date]
                                            ,[Status]
                                            ,[Work Description]
                                            ,[Labor Price]
                                            ,[Item]
                                            ,[Unit Price]
                                            ,[Qty]
                                            ,[Unit]
                                            ,[Item Price]
                                            ,[Mechanic]
                                            ,[Deposit])
                                        VALUES
                                            (@WOrder
                                            ,@Plate
                                            ,@Date
                                            ,@Status
                                            ,@WDesc
                                            ,@LPrice
                                            ,@Item
                                            ,@UPrice
                                            ,@Qty
                                            ,@Unit
                                            ,@IPrice
                                            ,@Mechanic
                                            ,@Deposit)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@WOrder", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "WRK" + Properties.Settings.Default.work;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Plate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@WDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18).Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Item", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18).Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Qty", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18).Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mechanic", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtWMech.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Deposit", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18).Value = numWDepo.Value;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
    Properties.Settings.Default.work = Properties.Settings.Default.work + 1;
}
```

Most of the columns can be null or empty. So I tried adding an `If-Else` for every `SqlParameter` that will be expecting `NULL` or empty. These are Status, WDesc, LPrice, Item, UPrice, Qty, Unit, and IPrice Parameters.

Now the whole parameter block is like this,

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@WOrder", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "WRK" + Properties.Settings.Default.work;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Plate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = plate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
if (dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value));
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", DBNull.Value.ToString()));
}
if (dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@WDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@WDesc", DBNull.Value.ToString()));
}
if (dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18)).Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LPrice", DBNull.Value));
}
if (dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Item", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Item", DBNull.Value.ToString()));
}
if (dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18)).Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UPrice", DBNull.Value));
}
if (dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qty", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value;
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qty", DBNull.Value));
}
if (dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Unit", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Unit", DBNull.Value.ToString()));
}
if (dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18)).Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IPrice", DBNull.Value));
}
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mechanic", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtWMech.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Deposit", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18).Value = numWDepo.Value;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now it can insert the values for every row inside my `DataGridView`. But is there a way how can I shorten or eliminate the `If-Else` statement? Or to make the code look cleaner?

Comment: You could use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) - `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value?.ToString() ?? DBNull.Value;` - the `?` after the value means "if not null, use this value" and the `??` means "if it is null, use this value"

Comment: Use Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) and check using the explorer that the database Table Columns are set to allow for Nulls.  Find the table and the open up columns.  The columns should show the type and then null like : ID (varchar(20), null)

Comment: @stuartd but how about if it is int or decimal or double? `Convert.ToDouble(dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value ?? DBNull.Value);` I have tried this but it returns an error

Comment: @Jepher sorry missed that. If the value is null, do you want to send `0` or `null` to the DB? For the first case it would be `Convert.ToDouble(dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);`

Comment: I didnt use `?? DBNull.Value` for numeric values. Just a normal `Parameters.Add` with a converted value. `cmd.Parameters.Add("@LPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18).Value = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridWork.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);` and it's working. It returns 0 for `Int` and 0.00 for `Decimal`. Thank you @stuartd

Answer (score 2):

You can use extension methods for this. e.g.

```
public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this DataGridViewRow sourceRow, int columnIndex, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    var o = sourceRow.Cells[columnIndex];
    if (o is T) return (T)o; 
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Use this as below:

```
dataGridWork.Rows[i].GetValueOrDefault<int>(1,0);
```

Comment: DataGridRow  != DataGridViewRow

Comment: As for you sample reference, it is pointing an error to `sourceRow` stating that `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'DataGridViewRow'`. I tried changing it to `this DataRow sourceRow`. And its pointing the error to `GetValueOrDefault<int>`